# ios popToRootViewControllerAnimated, its animated parameter setting issue

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller

See apple doc as below, does it mean we must set parameter animated as NO if we create navigation controller in advance? Such as the case as following. 
1. Create a navigation controller. 
2. Push view controllers in navigation controller. 
3. Then invoke popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

Ask this question dues to I have experienced many strange issues (including crash) regarding animated setting in my project. Any discussion will be appreciated.

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
Parameters
animated
Set this value to YES to animate the transition. Pass NO if you are setting up a  
navigation controller before its view is displayed.
```

Comment: How do you guys use this method in your project? Thanks.